# Execute List Query on Table

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam, alter-table

I want to change all table type on my database but not using SUPER USER. I want to try change for all table using ALTER TABLE script. Do you know how I can execute any query on list SELECT QUERY result?

This example query I create :

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_SCHEMA,".",TABLE_NAME," ENGINE = InnoDB;") AS Querys
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "database_name" AND ENGINE = "MyISAM"
```

and the result for that query is :

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                       Querys                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ALTER TABLE database_name.table_name1 ENGINE = innodb; |
| ALTER TABLE database_name.table_name2 ENGINE = innodb; |
| ALTER TABLE database_name.table_name3 ENGINE = innodb; |
| ALTER TABLE database_name.table_name4 ENGINE = innodb; |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

How I can execute that all query on the table result one by one/rows?

Comment: What is the issue with just running those 4 `ALTER TABLE` statements?

Comment: not has an issue, im just want to know how i can execute that all ALTER TABLE on table result using like script loop.

Comment: Copy and paste.  Else write a Stored Proc or app code to loop thru.